# Can I have one anonymous function as the value of two different properties in the same object?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, object-properties

Notice in the example below that both `create` and `update` are identical. I believe it is possible to have `update` just be an alias to `create`'s code without needing to write it out a second time.

```
this.VAROPS = {
    // variable operations
    create:     function(id, value) { variables[id] = value; }
,   delete:     function(id)        { delete variables[id]; }
,   update:     function(id, value) { variables[id] = value; }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, and you have two options:

1. Create an actual named function (which might be a local reference inside your scope) and assign it to both properties

   ```
   function foo() {}
   var bar = {
       baz: foo,
       xyzzy: foo
   }
   ```
2. Assign the first property's value to the second property *outside* of the object-literal definition

   ```
   var foo = {
       bar: function() {}
   }
   foo.baz = foo.bar;
   ```